# Rolling median in R

Tags: r, median

I need to calculate rolling median. And have following code

```
i <- 0
median_roll<-c("")
x<-c(1:10)
n<-2
y<-as.data.frame(x)
  while(i < length(x)-n){
    median_roll[i] <- median(y[i:i+n,])
    i <- i + 1  
  }
```

Which produce following reluts in median_roll

```
[1] "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9"
```

What i need is

```
[1] "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9"
```

Comment: It looks like i:i+n should be i:(i+n).

Comment: @Miff the produces the output of `[1] "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8"`

Comment: Why `median_roll<-c("")`?!? The median is a numeric value, start with `median_roll<-c()`.

Comment: A one-liner: `zoo::rollapplyr(y$x, width = 3L, FUN = median)`. Note that `n<-3L`, not 2.

Comment: @Miff thanks a lot. It works. Though i have to change the position of i+1 before median to include 9 as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are three options.
First the data.

```
x <- 1:10
y <- data.frame(x)
n <- 2L
```

**1** Base R, `for` loop.

```
median_roll <- numeric(length(x) - n)
for(i in seq_along(median_roll)){
  median_roll[i] <- median(y[i:(i+n), ])
}

median_roll
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**2** Base R, `sapply` loop.

```
sapply(seq_along(median_roll), \(i, n) median(y[i:(i+n), ]), n = 2L)
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**3** Package `zoo`.

```
zoo::rollapplyr(y$x, width = 3L, FUN = median)
#[1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. I need to edit my code according to @Miff and also change the position of i+1. But i am accepting your answer as well

Answer (score 1):

In R, indexing starts with `1` with which `i` should initialized accordingly.

```
i <- 1; x <- 1:10; r <- NULL; n <- 2
while (i - 1 + n < length(x)) {
  r[i] <- median(x[i:(i + n)])
  i <- i + 1
}
r
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

You can also use a `repeat` loop which might be more readable.

```
i <- 1; x <- 1:10; r <- NULL; n <- 2
repeat {
  r[i] <- median(x[i:(i + n)])
  i <- i + 1
  if (i - 1 + n == length(x))
    break
}
r
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

An `sapply(Map())` solution.

```
x <- 1:10; n <- 2
sapply(Map(`+`, list(1:(n + 1L)), seq(0, length(x) - n - 1L, n - 1L)), 
       \(s) median(x[s]))
# [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```